# Объясните как это работает?

Tags: node.js

только начинаю с node js работать.
Делаю по модели MVC

В контроллере создал вот такие функции.
Которые должны работать и работают  захожу по адресу http://localhost:3000/mysql/connect и если есть ошибка подключения к БД то меня перебрасывает на http://localhost:3000/mysql/error
Так все и отрабатывает
Но я не могу понять как меня перебрасывает, т.е. да там есть редирект, но как это работает через response?

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");

exports.error = function(request, response){
    response.render("./MySQL/viewMySQL.hbs");          //отправка ответа
};

exports.connect = function(request, response){
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({     //строка подключения к БД
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        database: "usersdb",
        password: "12345678@"
      });

    connection.connect(function(err){
        if (err) {        
            if(err.code == "ER_BAD_DB_ERROR"){ //если ошибка что не существует БД
                console.log("Error: connect to DB - not correct DataBase name");    //выводим в консоль сообщение что не верное имя БД
                response.redirect("/mysql/error");                                  //отправляем на страницу с описанием ошибки
            };
        }
        else{
            console.log("Connect to MySQL sever is succefull");
        }
    });  
};
```

Comment: https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/4.13.php используется код ответа 302 и ссылка, куда перенаправить https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302

Comment: это понятно ... не понятно другое почему если я убираю request, respons то программа не работает, мне важно понять цепочку работы

Comment: _но как это работает через response_ response отдает ответ браузеру, что надо перейти по указанному адресу, браузер переходит